# Cors Error when generating access token for SharePoint point online from a JavaScript application

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajaxform

Any help is much appreciated.
I'm trying to save data from a HTML form to a list in SharePoint online.
I'm using SharePoint REST API to add items to the list.
Ajax call to generate access token is throwing CORS error.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tenant_id/tokens/OAuth/2",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "<client_id>",
    "client_secret": "<client_secret>",
    "resource": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/site_url@tenant_id"
  }),
  headers: {
    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  success: function() {},
  error: function() {}
})
```

Note: This code returns an access token in postman. If I use that access token in SharePoint REST API, I'm able to add data to list. So the **challenge is generating access token from my JavaScript application** instead of Postman.
I can't use MSAL as I don't want to register my app in Azure AD.
I don't want a temporary fix like using a chrome extension to fix cors error or modifying rewrite rules in IIS.

I'm new to SharePoint, so any insights on alternate approaches would also be helpful.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I am having the same issue... If so could you please post your answer?